# Older services transmitting newer versions of protocol buffer 3 messages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Say, I have a protocol buffer message (in proto3) of the form

```
message A {
  int32 foo = 1;
}
```

I'm running servers X, Y, and Z written in Go that use these messages and pass them around with gRPC such that X talks with Y and Y talks with Z, i.e., X and Z talk via Y.

Alice designs a cool, new feature that requires adding a new field, bar, to message A and updates servers X and Z.

```
message A {
  int32 foo = 1;
  int32 bar = 2;
}
```

However, the deployed version of server Y does not recognize this new field and redeploying server Y to achieve this would quickly become very difficult in larger systems.

In a previous life, we used proto2 and all this worked fine because it would keep the unrecognized fields around. However, Google now recommends we use proto3 with gRPC and from my understanding, keeping unrecognized fields around is no longer supported at least in Go.

What is the recommended way to address this issue with proto3?

**Update:**
There is an open github issue about this
https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/272

Comment: Can you elaborate on "...keep the unrecognized fields around."?

Comment: Server Y would keep field bar as "unknown fields" on unmarshalling when it received the proto from Z. In turn, when Y would marshal and send this to X, bar would still be included in the wire format. Thus, X would receive the contents of bar, too, instead of them being dropped at Y.

Comment: As you say, it looks like this is a deliberate change between protocol versions [proto2](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#updating): "...unknown fields are not discarded, and if the message is later serialized, the unknown fields are serialized along with it..." whereas in [proto3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#updating): "...unknown fields are discarded when the message is deserialized...". I'd prefer to stick with proto2 rather than mix versions.

Comment: I think this protocol change is reasonable; the format of messages from server Y should remain unchanged if server Y remains unchanged.

Comment: I can see that we would at times want the format of messages to stay fixed. At other times, we would want Y to transmit fields it doesn't know about so that we don't have to redeploy servers for every small change in schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Any field for the future expansion needs:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any

I haven't used it myself, but if I understand correctly, even unrecognized Any field values should remain when the message is decoded and re-encoded.

Comment: any does help for submessages and work like extensions from proto2. It is definitely a part solution; it doesn't address all the issues though.